# Regular Expression not working correclty

Tags: ruby, regex

I am working on regular expressions.

```
id: 1 food: apple, banana
id: 2 food: orange
ids: 3 food: apple, banana
id: 4 food: hello, yellow
id: 5food: apple, banana
id:6 food: ,,,yellow
```

This is my regular expression code:

```
    pattern = /id[:] [[:digit:]]+ food[:] [a-z,]+/

id: 1 food: apple, banana
id: 2 food: orange
id: 4 food: hello, yellow
id: 6 food:,,,yellow
```

This expression is able to invalid everything except the last line. The last line in the list should not be printed. How can detect that the something doesn't start with ,,,

Edit: There is only one space allowed

Comment: I ran your regex with the new data and it gave the answer you wanted(1, 2, and 4).

Answer (score 1):

```
^id:\s+[0-9]+\s+food:\s+[a-z,\s]+$
```

This is the expression I used to match ids 1, 2, and 4 only.

See [rubular](http://rubular.com/r/tDulweeNB2) here

Comment: sorry, there was a typo in the code. There is only one space allowed between the words. How can I change it.

Comment: This will incorrectly match text following `"food: "`that contains multiple commas and/or spaces, and text that begins or ends with a comma or space. For example, `"id: 6 food: y,e,l,l,       o,w"  =~ /^id:\s+[0-9]+\s+food:\s+[a-z,\s]+$/ #=> 0`.

Answer (score 1):

```
▶ input.scan /^id:\s+\d+\s+food:\s+(?:[a-z]+(?:,\s)?)+$/
#⇒ [
#  [0] "id: 1 food: apple, banana",
#  [1] "id: 2 food: orange",
#  [2] "id: 4 food: hello, yellow"
# ]
```

Comment: there is only one space allowed between the words. I changed it to this: ^id:\s+\d+\sfood:\s+(?!,,)[a-z,\s]+$ and worked but I am not sure if changing to this will affect anything

Comment: If there is only one space allowed, this must be stated in the OP explicitly. In this case you simply do not need lookaheads. See an update.

Comment: I was saying there is only one space allowed, and only one comma between the food type. I tried the new code and it still doesn't work

Comment: I do not know what you have tried: this code perfectly works on the input given. If you are unable to provide correct test data, you should not expect to receive a working answer. Once again: the code above perfectly works.

Answer (score 1):

I understand that multiple contiguous spaces are not permitted.

```
r = /
    ^                   # match beginning of line
    id:\s               # match "id:" followed by a space
    \d+\s               # match > 0 digits followed by a space
    food:\s             # match "food:" followed by a space
    [[:alpha:]]+        # match > 0 letters
    (?:,\s[[:alpha:]]+) # match comma, space, > 0 letters in a non-capture group
    *                   # perform match on above non-capture group >= 0 times
    $                   # match end of string
    /x                  # free-spacing regex definition mode

str =<<_
id: 1 food: apple, banana
id: 2 food: orange
ids: 3 food: apple, banana
id: 4 food: hello, yellow
id: 5food: apple, banana
id:6 food: ,,,yellow
_

str.scan(r)
  #=> ["id: 1 food: apple, banana",
  #    "id: 2 food: orange",
  #    "id: 4 food: hello, yellow"]
```