# how to match this pattern using regex

Tags: ruby, regex

I am new to ruby and trying to use regular expression.
Basically I want to read a file and check if it has the right format.

```
Requirements to be in the correct format:
1: The word should start with from
2: There should be one space and only one space is allowed, unless there is a comma 
3: Not consecutive commas
4: from and to are numbers
5: from and to must contain a colon

from: z to: 2
from: 1 to: 3,4
from: 2 to: 3
from:3 to: 5 
from: 4 to: 5
from: 4 to: 7
to: 7 from: 6 
from: 7 to: 5
0: 7 to: 5
from: 24 to: 5
from: 7 to: ,,,5
from: 8 to: 5,,5
from: 9 to: ,5
```

If I have the correct regular expression, then the output should be:

```
from: 1 to: 3,4
from: 2 to: 3
from: 4 to: 5
from: 4 to: 7
from: 7 to: 5
from: 24 to: 5
```

so in this case these are the false ones:

```
from: z to: 2     # because starts with z
from:3 to: 5      # because there is no space after from:
to: 7 from: 6     # because it starts with to but supposed to start with from
0: 7 to: 5        # starts with 0 instead of from
from: 7 to: ,,,5  # because there are two consecutive commas
from: 8 to: 5,,5  # two consecutive commas
from: 9 to: ,5    # start with comma
```

Comment: This questions seems [vaguely familiar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39422263/regular-expression-not-working-correclty/39423003#39423003).

Answer (score 1):

OK, the regex you want is something like this:

```
from: \d+(?:,\d+)* to: \d+(?:,\d+)*
```

This assumes that multiple numbers are permitted in the `from:` column as well. If not, you want this one:

```
from: \d+ to: \d+(?:,\d+)*
```

To verify that the whole file is valid (assuming all it contains are lines like this one), you could use a function like this:

```
def validFile(filename)
    File.open(filename).each do |line|
        return false if (!/\d+(?:,\d+)* to: \d+(?:,\d+)*/.match(line))
    end
    return true
end
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is called negative lookahead. Specifically, `\d+(?!,,)` which says: match 1 or more consecutive digits not followed by 2 commas. Here is the whole thing:

```
str = "from: z to: 2
from: 1 to: 3,4
from: 2 to: 3
from:3 to: 5 
from: 4 to: 5
from: 4 to: 7
to: 7 from: 6 
from: 7 to: 5
0: 7 to: 5
from: 24 to: 5
from: 7 to: ,,,5
from: 8 to: 5,,5
from: 9 to: ,5
"

str.each_line do |line|
  puts(line) if line =~ /\Afrom: \d+ to: \d+(?!,,)/
end
```

Output:

```
from: 1 to: 3,4
from: 2 to: 3
from: 4 to: 5
from: 4 to: 7
from: 7 to: 5
from: 24 to: 5
```